# Xamarin.Forms with Web Service doesn't work

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms

I try to consume a Web Service API from a Xamarin.Forms Prism application, but it doesn't work. When I tried the same code in a Console Application it works.
when I debug the code, it exits at line:

```
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);
```

Here is the code of the classe I use:

```
public class RestClient<T>
    {
        private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:64049/api/Evenements";

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);
            var evenements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
            return evenements;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does 'exits' mean? Do you get an exception? An error? If so, what is the message? Also, try to put in a breakpoint at the `var evenements = ...` line. The debugger does not always understand the `await` keyword and skips over the rest of the code while it is executed correctly.

Comment: Thank's for your replay Gerald Versluis. 
When i put a breakpoint at  the var evenements = ... line it shows any thing because it skip at line before: var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);. Even when i put it in a try block it throws any exception it just skip!

Comment: Check your application output if it has any errors. Is this on iOS? Maybe it has to do with the fact that you need a secure connection. If you cannot try on a secure connection, you can test by adding this to your info.plist `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>`. **However** if that works, make sure you run your backend on a secure connection. Apple is likely to enforce the use of secure connections in the near future.

Comment: I'm deploying in Android. In fact, i'm using the same code to consume another Web Service API and it works well.

Comment: Closely examine your application output and see if any error messages come up there. Also try to start the browser app on your emulator and see if the URL can be reached when you type it in there.

Comment: use the IP or FQDN of your server, not localhost

Comment: It works, thanks Jason!, i used  my IP.